# How can I loot this stash in Crow's Perch?

Tags: the-witcher-3

While walking around the castle in Crow's Perch looking for interesting stuff, I found a hidden spot with a chest full of good stuff. After happily looting it, I turned to walk away, but scanned the area with my Senses just out of habit, and noticed this:

[image]

See this glowing stash? I really want to loot it as well, but for the life of me couldn't find a way.

I tried to:

- Jump over the wall - no luck, it's not possible.
- Break the wall with Aard - no effect.
- Burn the wall with Igni - no effect.
- Hit the wall with my fists - no effect.
- Jump like crazy near the stash to get the "loot" icon - success, but being in mid-air, I couldn't activate it by pressing "X".

Any other ideas?

Comment: As far as i can see (and observed myself in the game), thats not a chest but a simple barrel. So theres no interesting stuff in it and its just a misplaced barrel.

Comment: @Tyrmos interesting, thanks. But you actually reached that barrel?

Comment: Yes, after 10 minutes i got it, there was a bottle in it. I just walked against the wall on different positions and pressed E all the time, after a while i got it. By the way, should i answer that question or is my comment enough?

Comment: @Tyrmos answer would be better, thanks. Anyway, finished the game already, doubt it's worth getting back to it only for this. Thanks a bunch anyway, it might prove useful for others as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats just a misplaced barrel. After walking against the wall in different positions and angles, pressing E all the time i reached the barrel after some time, but there was just an empty bottle inside.